# getting "androidApplicationContext must be not null!" crashes from crash reporting service

Tags: android, crash-reports, illegalargumentexception, applicationcontext

after supporing linkedin social network, an app i'm working on has caused many crashes that the only thing that is written there is "androidApplicationContext must be not null!" .

i've searched the internet , and found only the next links as clues:

- http://pastebin.com/QeV9D8XH
- http://logs.nslu2-linux.org/livelogs/android-dev/android-dev.20120829.txt

  it says :

> ```
> Aug 28 17:15:23 <S3nsat10n> has anyone run across a stacktrace like this? http://pastebin.com/QeV9D8XH
> Aug 28 17:15:33 <S3nsat10n> has to do with a null app context inside the apache httpclient
> Aug 28 17:15:38 <Hodapp> wongk: yeah, I'm just really confused about why it's doing this...
> Aug 28 17:15:47 <S3nsat10n> highly modified httpclient it would seem, judging my the naf.gba package stuff
> Aug 28 17:15:51 <S3nsat10n> Seems to be happening only on Samsung Galaxy S devices, but I don't know if that's always the case.
> Aug 28 17:16:48 <wongk> S3nsat10n: never see that
> Aug 28 17:16:50 <wongk> seen
> Aug 28 17:17:17 <S3nsat10n> yeah :/
> Aug 28 17:17:22 <S3nsat10n> neither has most of the internet...
> Aug 28 17:17:23 <S3nsat10n> heh
> ```

has anyone else got this weird and super rare error?

if so how did you fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Two solutions :

- Use **HttpURLConnection** instead of **HttpClient**
- Create an instance of **HttpClient** in the main thread of your application, as soon as possible, for instance in its *onCreate* method.

More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18011842/982187).